# Spring : Send automated email to member and admin after timer expires

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, timer

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which there is Service desk functionality I am working on. So, as a part of Service desk, users can create issues and assign a support-team member. In that, they can also assign in how much time issue needs to be resolved. I am setting the time in java.sql.TimeStamp.

Now, when the time expires, I would like to send an email to the support-team admin, the person who created the issue and the support-team member responsible for resolving the issue.

If it was a normal scheduled or cron job, I can just write a @Scheduled method and get it over with, but here, I would like to check for example after 6 hours if the issue was resolved or not. How do I accomplish that? I have no idea to be honest.

Here is service layer part the SupportRequest :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SupportRequestServiceImpl implements SupportRequestService{

    private final SupportRequestDAO supportRequestDAO;

    @Autowired
    public SupportRequestServiceImpl(SupportRequestDAO supportRequestDAO){
        this.supportRequestDAO = supportRequestDAO;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SupportTeamService supportTeamService;
    @Override
    public int addSupportRequest(SupportRequest supportRequest, int assignedTeamId, Long groupId) {
        SupportTeam supportTeam = this.supportTeamService.getSupportTeamMemberById(assignedTeamId);
        if(!(supportTeam == null)){
            supportRequest.setCreationTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            supportRequest.setAssignedTeamMemberId(supportTeam.getTeamId());
            return this.supportRequestDAO.addSupportRequest(supportRequest,groupId);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know what else to show. Thanks a lot.

*Update*

Will something like this work?

```
long delay = 1000*60*60*12; // after 12 hrs
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                        // Task here ...
                        System.out.println("inside the main");
                        Integer id = new Integer(10);
                        Assert.assertNotNull(id);

                    }
                }, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of scenario, there should be background process running. That process will check for issues that has not been fixed in given time. Then this process will send a message to whoever you want and then continue running in background.

There are different ways of doing this.

**1. Batch Process** 
You can make batch process. Batch process will be running on your server, it will check for expired issues and then send mail to the support-team admin.

**2. Techniques for Real-time Updates**
You can also you real time update techniques in spring. Using this technique you will fire request after every given period that will check for expire issues. If any issue found that has not been fixed you can send mail. Please read the related document here : [Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Techniques for Real-time Updates](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates/)

**3. Web Socket**
Web socked can also be useful for these kind of task. Find the good source here : 
[SPRING FRAMEWORK 4.0 M2: WEBSOCKET MESSAGING ARCHITECTURES](http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html)

Comment: I already have cometd integrated into the application. Both the links do not provide any code, rather just some architectural notes, which are hardly useful.

Comment: I think shell scripting will be the good idea if you are using linux. Shell script will execute on server and can take care of this kind of task.

Comment: Can you give some relevant examples?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-ksh-csh-sendingfiles-mail-attachments/

Comment: Kindly let me know if there is some way to handle this using Spring.

Comment: Can you check the updated post at bottom, will something like that work?

Comment: You can also use spring task scheduling, write you code there and then spring will keep executing that task in given time. here is the link :
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html